# nth-child, change style of every other div with class name

Tags: html, css

I have got some elements on my page, they should all be styled the same except for every other one, where I just want to change some styling.

Here is the CSS which I was hoping would select the div inside the stack of different elements:

```
.stagger_reviews[class=inner]:nth-child(2n+2) {
    background-color:#003;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="stagger_reviews">
<!-- Later use PHP to load reviews, CSS should switch the images from left to right -->
    <article class="container box style1">
        <a style="background-image:url(images/blank-user.jpg); " href="#" class="image fit"></a>
        <div class="inner">
            <header>
                <h2>Martyn Ball</h2>
            </header>
            <p>
                I found this service on a Google Search, didn't expect it to be so great!
            </p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="container box style1">
        <a style="background-image:url(images/blank-user.jpg); " href="#" class="image fit"></a>
        <div class="inner">
            <header>
                <h2>Martyn Ball</h2>
            </header>
            <p>
                I found this service on a Google Search, didn't expect it to be so great!
            </p>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

As you can see I just want to adjust the one div inside each article which has the class name `inner`. And maybe some other elements as well but once I have this working I can do that.

The style isn't being applied to the second `inner` div, I have made about 4 copies of the article and none are being changed.

Comment: All `nth-child` asks is "Am I the nth child element of my parent element". You cannot limit this to classes, attributes or ids. It only cares about what I stated in the question. Even if it worked you'd have to put a space between `.stagger_reviews` and `[class=inner]`. And then it would still be identical to `.stagger_reviews :nth-child(2n+2)`.

Comment: So I can't do anything like this: .stagger_reviews > article > div:nth-child(2n2) {
  background-color:#003;
 }

Comment: You can, but `div` will be ignored.

Comment: Ah, I found the solution now, thanks.

Comment: Post it here so your question makes some sense later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, I put the nth-child in the wrong place.

```
.stagger_reviews > article:nth-child(2n+2) div[class=inner]
```

Comment: Again, the `article` part in the selector can be omitted, as well as the *direct descendant selector* `>`. It makes no difference. `.stagger_reviews :nth-child(2n+2) div.inner`.